# Searching with filter, not working correctly - Parse, Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, search, parse-platform, filter

When I call `refreshResults("test")` all search results are still displayed, instead of the ones that ONLY contain "test" in the business_name column in Parse. The arrays that I print when I use a filter contain data, though the wrong data.

The goal of this is a simple search - it is to return all results that contain the filter. Example: searching for "face" will return face, facebook, faced, faces, etc. because those results all contain the filter "face" in them. I am comparing the filter to the business_name field to see if any filters return a match.

The is_person value is always false because I am searching for businesses and not persons.

Here is the code:

```
func refreshResults(strFilter: String) {
    let progressIndicator = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    progressIndicator.labelText = "Loading..."

    resultsCompEmailArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    resultsCompNameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    resultsCompProfilePicArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    if (!strFilter.isEmpty) {
        print("searching with filter: ", strFilter)

        let q1 = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        q1.whereKey("is_person", equalTo: false)
        let q2 = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        q2.whereKey("business_name", containsString: strFilter)
        let otherQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([q2, q1])

        otherQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
            if (error == nil) {
                for obj in objects! {
                    self.resultsCompNameArray.append(obj.objectForKey("business_name") as! String)
                    self.resultsCompEmailArray.append(obj.objectForKey("username") as! String)
                    if let profilePic = obj.objectForKey("profile_picture") as? PFFile {
                        self.resultsCompProfilePicArray.append(profilePic)
                    }
                    self.resultsTable.reloadData()
                    print(self.resultsCompNameArray)
                }
            }
        })
    } 
}
```

Any useful comments appreciated, save the folly for someone else. Thanks.

Comment: So, you dont want the data with `is_person=false` that doesnt have the filtred `business_name`, right?

Comment: I need the search results to display any business_name as long as it's in the search filter. Example: searching for fo returns foo, foos, food, fodey because they all contain fo in them. The is_person part will always be false because I am searching businesses in my database and not persons - that is how I separate them. -- all of this is very similar to a simple Google search, all results that contain the search terms pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing an OR on your query. So, you are retrieving data that has is_person==false OR that contains the filtered string. So your results probably contains objects that doesnt fit the filter but is_person flag is false.

To resolve this you can do the following:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        query.whereKey("is_person", equalTo: false)
        query.whereKey("business_name", containsString: strFilter)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
            if (error == nil) {
                for obj in objects! {
                    self.resultsCompNameArray.append(obj.objectForKey("business_name") as! String)
                    self.resultsCompEmailArray.append(obj.objectForKey("username") as! String)
                    if let profilePic = obj.objectForKey("profile_picture") as? PFFile {
                        self.resultsCompProfilePicArray.append(profilePic)
                    }
                    self.resultsTable.reloadData()
                    print(self.resultsCompNameArray)
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your feedback. It was helpful. I have posted my answer for all to see.